# dplyr summarise on group not flattening data

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101188, 101192, 101193, 101196, 101198, 
101202, 101203, 101206, 101211, 101212, 101216, 101219, 101220, 
101222, 101223, 101224, 101226, 101227, 101228, 101229), LA = c("Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", "Barking and Dagenham", 
"Barking and Dagenham"), EstablishmentGroup = c("Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools", "Local authority maintained schools", 
"Local authority maintained schools")), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

If I run the following code I expect the final summarise to flatten the data and tell me

```
df %>%
  group_by(LA) %>%
  mutate(All_schools = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(LA, EstablishmentGroup, All_schools) %>%
  summarise(total = n(),
            per = total/All_schools)
```

> Barking and Dagenham  Local authority maintained schools  20  20  1

But it gives me 20 rows instead. I could use a distinct, but not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: Why do you think `total/All_schools` can reduce to 1 row per group when it has 20 rows? What aggregation are you expecting? Do you mean `total/min(All_schools)` or `total/sum(All_schools)` or `total/All_schools[1]` or `total/sample(All_schools,1)` or something else?

Comment: thanks, I'm getting my head messed up with dealing with the vector calculation. `total/min(All_schools)` (or max|unique|mean) is closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can summarise the count first, then mutate to calculate the percentage.

```
df %>%
  group_by(LA) %>%
  mutate(All_schools = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(LA, EstablishmentGroup, All_schools) %>% 
  summarise(total = n()) %>% 
  mutate(per = total/All_schools)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   LA, EstablishmentGroup [1]
  LA                   EstablishmentGroup                 All_schools total   per
  <chr>                <chr>                                    <int> <int> <dbl>
1 Barking and Dagenham Local authority maintained schools          20    20     1
```

Comment: Ah, so it's having the two items in the summarise that isn't allowing the rows to condense? EDIT: not quite, just read @r2evans above, if you havea vector calculation, the results will be a vector response